# How do I update an array in a model when polling the server

Tags: angularjs

I have a controller that polls the server every 5 seconds for a list of data. I update an array in my controller using

$scope.items = [];

then in my polling function

$scope.items = data;

The problem I'm having is that if I set any values on any of the items they are overwritten when updating. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What kind of values are you setting?

Comment: data is an array of json objects

Comment: So you get an array of objects from the server, then do something on the Angular side that updates one of the objects, then pull in new data from the server which overrides your changes? Correct? If so, that is more of a design problem than something that has to do with Angular. What is the desired behaviour? Should it always keep the data modified front end or should it try to merge if data has changed on both ends at the same time?

Comment: If you always wanted to keep the data from the front end you would need to loop through the list and .push() into the array if the object (based on some unique identifying key) does not already exist. An object might be better for this than an array depending on the usecase.

Comment: Thanks Erik, that's what I ended up doing.